# Custom jQuery-function not working on WordPress even though other loaded jQuery functions are working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using WordPress 3.8.1. I want to use this function to use sticky header

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $header = $("header"),
        $clone = $header.before($header.clone().addClass("clone"));

    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        console.log(fromTop);
        $("body").toggleClass("down", (fromTop > 200));
    });
});        
</script>
```

But it is not working for me and I don't know why. I know that jQuery is shared to my WordPress because Flexslider 2 is now working fine.

Comment: Any ouput on developer console? What do you mean by Flexslider 2 now working.

Comment: i'm a new programmer dont know about developer console , i think that if jquery library did'nt share to my wordpress flexslider dont work

Comment: does .on() work on jquery that wordpress using ( i have to use .live() instead)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now you can write your jQuery code like this:

```
j(document).ready(function(){
    j('.class').event(function(){

      // your action............

    });
  });
```

Just assign the `noConflict()` function to a variable, and use that variable instead of `$` seen in jQuery code.

Comment: i tired to try , it makes me crazy , i could cr8 a fake theme to show my problem https://www.mediafire.com/?59rk29f5ef4j6ad , if u could to solve this please upload it thanks

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party here, but the correct solution to this is:

Understand that in WordPress, jQuery is loaded in [no conflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) mode.  This means that the `$` variable is *not* referencing jQuery.

But, by modifying your script to use a no-conflict-safe document ready, you can use the `$` within the function.

Modify your script as follows:

```
// original code - doesn't work, because $ is not jQuery in WordPress
// $(document).ready(function() {
// shorthand no-conflict-safe document ready:
jQuery(function($) {
    // Now $ is safe to use - it references jQuery within this doc ready function
    var $header = $("header"),
        $clone = $header.before($header.clone().addClass("clone"));

    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        console.log(fromTop);
        $("body").toggleClass("down", (fromTop > 200));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the jquery file in your header (assuming you have the jquery file in your templates folder, but it can be anywhere, as long as you reference it correctly):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

Example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#container").alert("blah");
     $(".goodshelf_ul li:first").css("border-top: none;");
     $(".custom_ul li:first").addClass("first");
     $("#footer .frame:last").css("margin: 0;");
     $("#footer .frame:last").addClass("last");
});
```

I use jquery on all my wordpress sites and it works fine
hope this helps.