# Collapse should work without using Jquery.js

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and i want to include collapse and Hidden code of some other text in same Page but its not working using this code .Actually I recognized the problem is in the line.

jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :undefined;

If  I am deleting this line Collapse is not working but the Other Part of the Section is working. I need both to be worked at the same section.Please give me solution for the problem.

```
       if ( !(eventHandle = elemData.handle) ) {
        eventHandle = elemData.handle = function( e ) {
            // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
            // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
            return typeof jQuery !== core_strundefined && (!e || jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type) ?
                jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :
                undefined;
        };
```

Comment: Plz Create http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

It is jQuery conflict issue.
search about jQuery conflict in google.
or change the position of jQuery code with its appropriate jQuery file included.

Comment: no need to delete any line of code in this problem ok ??

Comment: No change occured even the position is changed

Comment: use jquery no conflict click http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948053/jquery-function-not-working-on-wordpress/21949790#21949790 to refer my earlier answer.