# Adding jquery to wordpress site

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am very new to working with jquery, so I am sorry if this is very basic stuff.

I have been playing around on jsfiddle and got some jquery to do what I want it to (add a class to parent when you hover over a child), but when I take the code and try to add it to my wordpress site, it just will not work.

This is my code I am trying to add:

```
$('.explore > .country').hover(function() {
$(this).parent().toggleClass('hover');
})
```

I know wordpress doesn't like $ for function and I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$('.explore > .country').hover(function() {
$(this).parent().toggleClass('hover');
})
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Here is also a link to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0n5dxee1/1/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to enqueue jQuery first. It comes built in to wordpress but doesn't come pre-activated.

Search your theme's function.php file for "wp_enqueue", if there is a function there already enqueuing scripts add the following line to it..

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

Otherwise, create your own enqueue scripts function..

```
// function to enabled (enqueue) scripts in wordpress
function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_scripts');
```

---

**update**

---

**Alternatively**

You can create a js file with your custom code and enqueue for use site wide.

1. Create a file named mycustomfunctions.js
2. Put this in it..

   ```
   // describe function here
   jQuery(function() {
       jQuery('.explore > .country').hover(function() {
           jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('hover');
       })
       jQuery('.explore > .community').hover(function() {
           jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('hover2');
       })
   });
   ```
3. In your child theme root folder create a new folder, name it 'js'
4. Put `mycustomfunctions.js` in `js` folder
5. Edit your child themes functions.php to include..

   ```
   // function to enable (enqueue) scripts in wordpress
   function enqueue_scripts() {
       wp_enqueue_script('mycustomfunctions', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/mycustomfunctions.js', array('jquery') );
   }
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_scripts');
   ```

*note* - no need to enqueue jquery separately as we've listed it as a dependency for mycustomfunctions (see array), wordpress will enqueue jquery automatically because of this required dependency.

Comment: I created a functions.php in my child theme and added this, but still did not fix the problem. Also tried what Monica suggested by replacing the $ with 'jQuery' and that did not fix it either.

Comment: Regarding no conflict here's how to write it using jQuery instead of $. Both hovers are wrapped in a document ready function. http://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/0n5dxee1/2/

Comment: Also, are you sure you were in the right theme folder? Functions.php is a pretty common file, found in most themes.

Answer (score 1):

try this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21949790/4426282

using $ will return undefined, try jQuery instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly all you have to do is put:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

between the two `<head>` tags

Answer (score 0):

```
function myCustomScript() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.explore > .country').hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('hover');
    })
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'myCustomScript' );
```

Would you please add above code in your `functions.php` ?