# Replace word and add style Javascript snippet in Elementor: Hello Wordpress Theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I'd like to replace the word "Product" for the word "Ingredients" and make it red in this page (https://shop.echemco.com/product/product-test-01/). I'm using Elementor with wordpress theme Hello and this is the code I'm using. I tried putting that code in an HTML module and also in the functions.php file (none of them worked):

```js
$('h3').each(function() {
   var text = $(this).text();
   $(this).html(text.replace('Product', '<span style="color: red;">Ingredients</span>')); 
});
```

```html
<h3>Product Information</h3>
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: And it's not working. Understood. Can you give an example of the html in need of replacing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom jQuery-function not working on WordPress even though other loaded jQuery functions are working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948053/custom-jquery-function-not-working-on-wordpress-even-though-other-loaded-jquery)